# If two sets have empty interior closures, does the interior of the closures's union is contained in the union of the interior of the closures?

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

Is that true that $(\overline{X})^{\circ} = (\overline{Y})^{\circ}  = \emptyset \Rightarrow (\overline{X \cup Y})^{\circ} \subseteq (\overline{X})^{\circ} \cup (\overline{Y})^{\circ}$, where $^{\circ}$ stands for "interior of the set"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true.

Assume that $U \subseteq \left(\overline{X \cup Y}\right)^\circ$ is open and non-empty. Then $U \setminus \overline{Y}$ is open (as intersection of open $U$ and open complement to $\overline{Y}$) and non-empty (otherwise $U \subseteq \overline{Y}$ and $\overline Y$  has non-empty interior). But $U \setminus \overline{Y} \subseteq \overline{X}$, so $\overline X$ has non-empty interior.

Comment: that's great! Thank you very much! I was trying to prove this by using the equality $(\overline{X \cup Y})^{\circ} = (\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y})^{\circ}$ but it was not very prolific.

Comment: This equality is not true. Take, for example, $X = [0, 1]$, $Y = [1, 2]$ in $\mathbb R$ with standard topology.

Comment: I think it's true @mihaild, because $\overline{X \cup Y} = \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$. The example you gave is a counter-example for $(\overline{X \cup Y})^{\circ} = (\overline{X})^{\circ} \cup (\overline{Y})^{\circ}$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.